# How to plug a piece of code into a Jsp page from a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to plug a piece of code dynamically into a Jsp from a servlet , Below is the example of what I am trying to do. how can I achieve this?

Example :
Basically I want to plug this to a jsp ex: homepage.jsp from a servlet.
%@ include file="header.jsp" %>

My new homepage.jsp would look like this.

```
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %> 
<html>
<head><title>First JSP</title></head>
 <body>
 <center>
 <p>Thanks for visiting my page.</p>
 </center>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Thanks,
Beginner.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965914/java-jsp-vs-servlet

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your import statement is correct.

The piece of code you are including will be placed exactly where your include statement is now. I am assuming your header is part of you HTML so it should live inside the HTML tag at the appropriate spot.

The content of the file attribute is the relative URL. So the the way you have it "head.jsp" would have to live in the same folder the file importing it. If the URL to the file to be included would start with a slash "/" this would be interpreted as an absolute path on the serve, otherwise it is considered a relative path from the file that is including the fragment.

HINT: The convention for the file extension for your included fragment is ".jspf" as in Java Server Page Fragment instead of ".jsp". This convention is not mandatory though.

Comment: Hello, sorry If my question doesn't explain what exactly I need. I need that include statement to be plugged into my jsp from a servlet. Basically ,I want to insert that line of code into a Jsp dynamically from a servlet.